# Javascript getting a function to execute based on and/or

Tags: javascript, function

My code:

```
let buttonScore = document.querySelector('.button-score');
let paraScore = document.querySelector('.para-score');

buttonScore.addEventListener('click', scoreEntry);

function scoreEntry() {
    let scoreOne = Number(prompt('Enter first score'));
    let scoreTwo = Number(prompt('Enter second score'));
    
    if (scoreOne > scoreTwo) {
        scoreCheck();
    }
}

function scoreCheck() {
    if (scoreOne > 9) {
        paraScore.textContent = 'Excellent!';
    } else if (scoreOne < 7) {
        paraScore.textContent = 'Not enough';
    } else {
        paraScore.textContent = 'Good';
    }
}
```

Upon the user entering the two scores, I want the script to select the bigger score of the two and run scoreCheck() on it. I assume my problem has to do with non-global variables. In case this can also be done with one function instead of two, I'd also like to know please.

Would very much appreciate clarification, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the variable a parameter to the second function.

Instead of testing whether one score is higher than the other, use `Math.max()` to select the higher score, and pass that as the argument.

```
function scoreEntry() {
    let scoreOne = Number(prompt('Enter first score'));
    let scoreTwo = Number(prompt('Enter second score'));
    
    scoreCheck(Math.max(scoreOne, scoreTwo));
}

function scoreCheck(score) {
    if (score > 9) {
        paraScore.textContent = 'Excellent!';
    } else if (score < 7) {
        paraScore.textContent = 'Not enough';
    } else {
        paraScore.textContent = 'Good';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, but how do I make the script apply scoreCheck() on the bigger number? If the user enters scoreTwo as the bigger score, scoreCheck() doesn't apply

Comment: @troubledcoder ... I don't really know what the OP wants to achieve, but from the above comment's question a sophisticated guess was ... `if (scoreOne > scoreTwo) { scoreCheck(scoreOne, scoreTwo); }` **`else { scoreCheck(scoreTwo, scoreOne); }`**

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thank you Peter, from the OP

Comment: @Barmer ... you are likewise welcome ... :-)

Comment: One last question please @PeterSeliger , could this have been done with one function, or are 2 functions necessary here?

Comment: @troubledcoder what does it mean ... "*or are 2 functions necessary*" ... 2 functions like the both functions which already exist ... `scoreEntry` and `scoreCheck` ... or twice the function call of `scoreCheck` within the suggested `if (...) {...} else {...}` block?

Comment: @PeterSeliger A followup: while the code is working now, it says that scoreTwo in scoreCheck(scoreOne, scoreTwo) is not in use, graying it out. Should I remove it and instead just keep scoreCheck(scoreOne)?

Comment: @troubledcoder ... this most probably comes from the static code analysis build/plugged into your IDE ... and it is due to `scoreCheck` which alway uses just its 1st argument. Thus, if everything else already worked as expected, change the `if ... else ...` to ... `if (scoreOne > scoreTwo) { scoreCheck(scoreOne); } else { scoreCheck(scoreTwo); }`

Comment: @troubledcoder See my changes to the answer. I didn't notice earlier that the second function only used one of the scores.